# Proper use of std::enable_if or how to replace it

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

Is this proper use of std::enable_if?
It works, but is it correct?

```
//*.h file

template <typename T>
static typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type 
randomFrom(const T min, const T max);


template <typename T>
static typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>::type 
randomFrom(const T min, const T max);
```

.

```
//*.inl file

template <typename T>
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type 
Math::randomFrom(const T min, const T max)
{
    static std::default_random_engine re((unsigned long)time(0));
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> uni(min, max);
    return static_cast<T>(uni(re));
}

template <typename T>
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>::type 
Math::randomFrom(const T min, const T max)
{
    static std::default_random_engine re((unsigned long)time(0));
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T> uni(min, max);
    return static_cast<T>(uni(re));
}
```

How can I rewrite it, to achieve cleaner interface? Like:

```
template <typename T>
static T randomFrom(const T min, const T max);
```

BTW with boost I had something like:
(i do not want to use boost)

```
typedef typename boost::mpl::if_<
        boost::is_floating_point<T>,
        boost::uniform_real<>,
        boost::uniform_int<>>::type dist_type;
```

and whole behavior was solved in single function. But there is nothing like `std::if` right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your usage is fine, and very much idiomatic.

The equivalent to Boost.MPL's `if_` would be `std::conditional`:

```
typedef typename std::conditional<
        std::is_floating_point<T>::value,
        std::uniform_real_distribution<T>,
        std::uniform_int_distribution<T>>::type dist_type;
```

Comment: Hah, +1 for `std::conditional`, hadn't thought about it (and didn't read the boost MPL part of the question, I admit). Solves it in a single function.

Comment: that is exactly what I have been looking. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Simply wrap them I guess?

```
template <typename T>
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type 
randomFrom_helper(const T min, const T max)
{
    static std::default_random_engine re((unsigned long)time(0));
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> uni(min, max);
    return static_cast<T>(uni(re));
}

template <typename T>
inline typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T>::type 
randomFrom_helper(const T min, const T max)
{
    static std::default_random_engine re((unsigned long)time(0));
    std::uniform_real_distribution<T> uni(min, max);
    return static_cast<T>(uni(re));
}


template <typename T>
T randomFrom(const T min, const T max)
{
return randomFrom_helper(min,max);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you wrap them like *Mr.Anubis* also suggests, you can even drop the (sometimes a bit cryptic) SFINAE hack and use overloading instead:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T>
    T randomFromImpl(const T min, const T max, const std::true_type&)
    {
        //integer implementation
    }

    template <typename T>
    T randomFromImpl(const T min, const T max, const std::false_type&)
    {
        //float implementation
    }
}

template <typename T>
T randomFrom(const T min, const T max)
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, "unsupported type");
    return detail::randomFromImpl(min, max, std::is_integral<T>());
}
```

Other than that, your use of `std::enable_if` is indeed correct, even if not necessarily needed (but I guess it's a matter of taste if you prefer SFINAE or overloading).

Comment: Note than SFINAE trigger a O(N) template instanciation while tag dispatching is O(1). So prefer tag dispatching whenever possible:)